# What temperature will create amorphous TiSi?

Tags: material-science, electronics

At what temperature will create [amorphous TiSi](http://www.google.com/search?q=temperature+amorphous+TiSi)?

I think it's around 500 Celsius but I'm not sure.

Answer (score -1):

The Binary Phase Diagram of Si-Ti , shows nothing of any interest below 860 deg C.  The solubility of Ti in solid Si is considered to be negligible, to very small.   What specifically is your interest; Titanium metallurgy, or doping of silicon; and what do you mean by "amorphous"  ?  The full Si-Ti phase diagram, from zero to 100 % Si (atomic) covers the 860 t0 2120 deg C range, but a lot is conjecture.

Answer (score -1):

Analysing the links listed- its not a thermal process (no melting involved) that use to produce Ti88Si12 films. Its vapour deposition- a multitude of processes that operate at or below atmospheric pressure. 
I don't think this films would survive thermal processing.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_vapor_deposition